# Error doing processing.runalg

Tags: pyqgis

I have been working in this code but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "c:/users/miguel~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpdsyhqn.py", line 17, in processing.load(reproj["G:\pyQGIS\MIRAR EN MI ORDENADOR\nuevo.asc"]) KeyError: 'G:\pyQGIS\MIRAR EN MI ORDENADOR\nuevo.asc'
```

In QGIS, this error is printed with "\"in every path, even if I only write "\" in my paths of the code.

```
import processing   
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

#Processing.initialize()
#Processing.updateAlgsList()

raster = QgsRasterLayer("G:\\pyQGIS\MIRAR EN MI ORDENADOR\\MDT05-0559-H30-LIDAR.asc","MDT05")
print rasterLyr.isValid()
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25830, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
raster.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([rasterLyr])

#25830
reproj = processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", raster, "EPSG: 25830", "EPSG:4326", '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, False, 1, False, "extraParam", "G:\\pyQGIS\\MIRAR EN MI ORDENADOR\\nuevo.asc")
processing.load(reproj["G:\\pyQGIS\\MIRAR EN MI ORDENADOR\\nuevo.asc"])
```

Can you tell me the code: `print(repr(reproj))` which makes the following output?

```
{'OUTPUT': 'G:\\pyQGIS\\MIRAR_COMP\\nuevo.tif'}
```

Comment: `G:\\pyQGIS\MIRAR EN MI ORDENADOR\\`  is not a valid path for processing (spaces)

Comment: Can you insert the debug statement `print(repr(reproj))` just before the last line?

Comment: I have changed the routes: MIRAR_COMP (I have eliminated the spaces) and I have included the code you told. This is the output: {'OUTPUT': 'G:\\pyQGIS\\MIRAR_COMP\\nuevo.tif'} I HAVE USED NOW A .tif

Comment: I can't find any "nuevo.tif" file output

Comment: I rolled back your last change since it converted the question into an answer which makes it hard to follow for future readers. Please leave comments for updates like this. FYI: You can also answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `processing.runalg` is a dictionary containing key, map pairs where the keys are defined by the algorithm.

In the case of `gdalogr:warpreproject` there is one output with the name `OUTPUT` created which points to the location where the result is. To access it, you can use the following code:

```
processing.load(reproj['OUTPUT'])
```

**About `\` and `/`**

Sidenote: Windows normally uses `\` for separating paths which was a terrible decision for programmers because the same character is used for escape sequences in strings, that's why you have to double them. Sometimes.

I recommend always using `/` instead of `\`. It's understood by Windows but also by other platforms, so it makes your code portable. It's also easier to read and write because you don't have to double the character. If you run into troubles you can still use pythons [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) which will dynamically translate to the appropriate character for the current platform.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the changes. May I ask a question? Why does EXTRA <ParameterString> accept an empty string? Thank you very much

Comment: I don't know but if you don't find the answer and deem the question important enough, ask a new question :)

Comment: According to loading the new layer, get this error: KeyError: 'G:\\pyQGIS\\MIRAR_COMP\\nuevo.tif' when I establish the same route of output. Is it possible to use a QgsRasterLayer to load the otput?